# Inserting unsigned integer value into bytebuffer, maintaining binary representation

Tags: java, bytebuffer, unsigned-integer

I'm trying to put the following binary representation into a bytebuffer for 4 bytes. But since Java doesn't do unsigned, I'm having trouble: 11111111000000001111111100000000

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);

bb.putInt(Integer.parseInt("11111111000000001111111100000000", 2));
//throws numberformatexception
```

Negating the most significant bit seems to change the binary string value because of how two's compliment works:

```
bb.putInt(Integer.parseInt("-1111111000000001111111100000000", 2));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(bb.getInt(0)));
//prints 10000000111111110000000100000000
```

It's important that the value is in this binary format exactly because later it will be treated as an unsigned int. How should I be adding the value (and future values that start with 1) to the bytebuffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse it as a `long` first, and cast the result:

```
int value = (int) Long.parseLong("11111111000000001111111100000000", 2);
```

That handles the fact that `int` runs out of space, because there's plenty of room in a `long`. After casting, the value will end up as a negative `int`, but that's fine - it'll end up in the byte buffer appropriately.

EDIT: As noted in comments, in Java 8 you can use `Integer.parseUnsignedInt("...", 2)`.

Comment: Thanks, Jon Skeet! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For what it's worth, Java8 adds Integer.parseUnsignedInt, which would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Guava's [UnsignedInts.parseUnsignedInt(String string, int radix)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html#parseUnsignedInt(java.lang.String,%20int)) and [UnsignedInts.toString(int x,int radix)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html#toString(int,%20int)) methods:

```
int v = UnsignedInts.parseUnsignedInt("11111111000000001111111100000000", 2);
System.out.println(UnsignedInts.toString(v, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    bb.putInt((int)Long.parseLong("11111111000000001111111100000000", 2));
```